using handlebars to display data from a returned promise
I am trying to display data in my template that is returned from an api fetch.  I'm using Node with Fastify.
The code I am using to send to the handlebars helper from my template is:
value="{{fetchClass this.CERTIFICATION}}"

I then send this to my helper:
Handlebars.registerHelper('fetchClass', async function(str) {
  try {
    const response = await fetchClassification(str);
      console.log('Response: ', response);
      return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching classification:', error);
  }
});

Which in turns sends to:
async function fetchClassification(parameter) {
  fetch(`https://api.example.com/dictionary/CERTIFICATION/${parameter}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const classification = data.meaning.classification;
        return classification;
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
}

I can console log the results and it is correct ("Standard") but the helper returns:
Response:  Promise { undefined }

I also tried doing the fetch inside my helper like:
Handlebars.registerHelper('fetchClass', function(str) {
  fetch(`https://api.example.com/dictionary/CERTIFICATION/${str}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const classification = data.meaning.classification;
        console.log('Class: ', classification);
        if (classification) {
          return classification;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
});

While the console log shows correctly (Class:  Standard), it doesn't get displayed in my template.. ugh
What am I doing wrong?

it seems there is a missing: return fetch(...

that still doesn't help me resolve a promise..  I'm thinking I need to use promised-handlebars npm module?

I don't think Handlebars is going to be able to handle a Promise returned from a helper. I think you will need to fetch the data and then render the template, not fetch the data as part of the rendering.
